# Search text in View

Tags: view, plsql, toad

Usually I use this query to look for string in Stored Procedure's text:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ALL_SOURCE a
 where UPPER(A.TEXT) like UPPER('%text%')
```

But it seems not to work with the VIEW.

I tried with `ALL_VIEW` table but the there is not a field with the text (neither `OID_TEXT`).

Is there a query to look for words in View's text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In table `all_views` text column is of datatype `long`. You can't search LONGs directly. LONGs can't appear in the WHERE clause. They can appear in the `SELECT` list though so you can use that to narrow down the number of rows you'd have to examine.

Oracle has recommended converting LONGs to CLOBs for at least the past 2 releases.

First convert LONG type column to CLOB type then use like condition, for example:

```
create table tbl_clob as
select to_lob(long_col) lob_col 
from tbl_long;

select * 
from tbl_clob 
where lob_col like '%form%';
```

Comment: Thank you!

Is there a way to see what the clob "contains"?

Comment: I gave the solution in my answer..Convert the column to clob and then do the search. Or you need to write a PLSQL block to do so.

Comment: Yes, sorry... in the result I could only see (HUGECLOB) but clicking on the field I found all the code. Thank you again!!